# Why does `FindInstance` refuse to find a second instance, in a number theory problem?

Tags: diophantine-equations, findinstance

Hi I am looking for reversible Markov generating matrices of order three, whose upper (2,2) block has integer eigenvalues. There are 5 free parameters;  I specified  2

```
Ps = {{-a - a b c /(x y), a, a b c /(x y)}, {x, -x - b, b}, {c, 
    y, -c - y}};
Ps.{1, 1, 1}(*check generating matrix*)
B = Ps[[{1, 2}, {1, 2}]]; B // MatrixForm
Id = IdentityMatrix[2]; re = s Id - B;
cf = CoefficientList[Det[re], s]
de = cf[[2]]^2 - 4 cf[[1]] // FullSimplify
fi = FindInstance[(de /. {a -> 2, y -> 3}) == k^2 && b > 0 && c > 0 &&
    x > 0, {b, c, x, k}, Integers]
```

Mathematica 11.3 finds it in a blink, so I got my exam with integer answers for tomorrow. Since I need also a sample exam, I ask now for two instances, but FindInstance refuses.
Same thing happens if I change y to 4 and to 5. What happens: is FindInstance lazy, or did I discover a new "exam uniqueness theorem"?

Comment: Allowing more freedom in the a and y: FindInstance[de == k^2 && b > 0 && c > 0 && x > 0 && a > 0, {a, b, c, x, k, y}, Integers, 10] seems to work.